# how to display a row in gridview for insertion on a button click event

Tags: gridview

Requirement: On clicking  (insert) button, a new row should be displayed in the gridview. Also there is save and cancel links beside the row.

.aspx

```
                <asp:Panel ID = "pnlForAddCategory" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" >
                <asp:GridView ID="grdAddCategory" runat="server" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="1" Width="90%" BackColor="#CCCCCC"
                style="table-layout:fixed" GridLines="None"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="tableHeaderRow" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="tableRow" RowStyle-CssClass="tableAltRow"
                RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  OnRowEditing="grdAddCategory_RowEditing"   OnRowCancelingEdit="grdAddCategory_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="grdAddCategory_RowUpdating" ShowFooter="true" >
                <Columns>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="70px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<input value='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>' type="checkbox"  id="chkbxCtgry" name="chkbxCtgry" />--%>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxCtgry" runat="server" />


                </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>




                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Name">      

                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPrdCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddProductName" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>' >

                <asp:ListItem Text="maths" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="history" />
                 <asp:ListItem Text="science" />
                 <asp:ListItem Text="social" />


                </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>





                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Name" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblctgryName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryName") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxctgryName" runat="server" Text= '<%# Bind("CategoryName") %>'  ToolTip='<%#Eval("CategoryId")%>' Maxlength="255"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>


                   <asp:TemplateField  Visible="false" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryId" Visible="false"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryId") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxCategoryId" runat="server" Text= '<%# Bind("CategoryId") %>'  Visible="false"  Maxlength="255"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStatus"  runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>



                <asp:ListItem Text="Active" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Inactive"  />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Update" ButtonType="Button" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
                    </asp:CommandField>



                </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FooterTemplate` of the `GridView` for that.

Example: [How to insert record using GridView](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article180.aspx)